# Problem Binding to Combobox SelectedIndex

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I thought binding ComboBox.SelectedIndex to an integer column should be simple but I can't get it to work.

In VB.NET windows forms app with SQL Server, using a BindingSource, I have various textboxes and checkboxes bound to my BindingSource and all works perfectly.  I have an integer field (LengthUnitFlag) that acts as a flag indicating units for length measurements.
I manually entered the item collection in the ComboBox designer.

Inches, Feet, Yards, Millimeters, Centimeters, Meters

On Form Load I bind the SelectedIndex to my BindingSource(bsrcProducts) like this:

```
cboLengthUnits.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", bsrcProducts, "LengthUnitFlag")
```

The ComboBox never fills.  As I move from one product record to the next, the ComboBox text remains blank.  If I select one of the options from the dropdown, the LengthUnitFlag field is not updated based on the new SelectedIndex.
I also tried creating a table of units with a UnitID and a UnitType to be the source for the dropdown list but, I haven't been able to bind the selectedIndex nor the SelectedValue to the LengthUnitFlag field in my table.

It seems like this should be really simple but I don't know what I am missing.
I can just update the record based on the SelectedIndexChanged event but that seems rather brute force.
What is the best way to ty a simple flag column to a combobox?

Comment: You cannot bind the `SelectedIndex` property. Also, do you have more than one Row that's using the same `LengthUnitFlag` (so, the same Unit of measure)? If so, how is the binding supposed to work? If you have Rows that use all a different measure instead, set the `DisplayMember` to the name of the Unit of measure (maybe coming from a cross-joined table), the `ValueMember` to `LengthUnitFlag` and the `DataSource` to your BindingSource (specifying a DataMember is required), in this order.

Comment: Of course, in the latter scenario, you don't set the DataBindings of the ComboBox: it's already *bound*.

Comment: Jimi - Strangely, I have searched high and low on binding to 'SelectedIndex' property of ComboBox and nowhere seen that you can't do this.  Wow, feels good to stop banging my head against that wall.

Comment: I don't mean that the property is not *bindable*: it is, but it's not a two-way binding. If you move the Current record, `SelectedIndex` is changed, but changing the `SelectedIndex` value doesn't change the Current record. You should specify whether your Rows all have different `LengthUnitFlag` values.

Comment: @Jimi hmm.. There must have been something incorrect about the binding I made because the ComboBox selected item did not change as I went from one row to the next where the `LengthUnitFlag` was changing.  Yes, every record could have a different `LengthUnitFlag` value.

Comment: Yes, there's something wrong in the binding. -- *every record could have a different LengthUnitFlag value*, the point is if all have a different `LengthUnitFlag` or more rows can have the same value.

Comment: @Jimi - thanks for taking the time to help me out.  To clarify, the `LengthUnitFlag` value must be one of the six options.  FYI, I found the problem with the binding, I mistakenly added the binding to the wrong control.  Once corrected, I noted that moving from one record to the next the combobox selectedindex correctly reflected the underlying data.  However, if I ever tried changing the selection then, as you pointed out, the underlying data did not change and also, the combobox selectedindex remained fixed and no longer updated as I moved through the records. Thanks issue resolved.